# I can't get my Unity player to move in the direction it is facing using Rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

```
    public Rigidbody playerBody;
    public float speed = 5f;

    void Update()
    {

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector3( horizontal * speed, playerBody.velocity.y, vertical * speed);

    }
```

I cant get the character to move in the direction the camera is facing.

Comment: You are not doing anything with the player, what are you expecting? You need to move it, for example using the Translate method or directly changing its transform

Comment: It is moving, just not in the direction it is facing

Comment: If I use transform.forward it says Vector3 can't be converted to a float. How do I convert it t a float?

Answer (score 0):

Try using MovePosition instead of velocity

```
playerBody.MovePosition(new Vector3( horizontal * speed, playerBody.velocity.y, vertical * speed));
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that out.  Thanks. But how does that make a difference to which way the player will move. I need to move towards where the camera is facing.

Comment: It just transports me to a random location.

Comment: try removing * speed or multiply the speed by Time.deltaTime

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, but I tinkered with it and got it done. Here is the code.

```
playerBody.velocity = transform.forward * speed * vertical + transform.up 
                      * playerBody.velocity.y + transform.right * speed * horizontal;
```